# Name of next tag badge and progress for it are jammed together if name is too long

Tags: bug, profile-page, information-display, badge-progress

When I was looking at my profile, I discovered that the name of my next tag badge was jammed with the bar showing my progress for me. It looks like this happens when the tag name is too long.

[image: Logged in tag badge progress]

This happens even if I am logged out. The display issue is not as severe only because the icon next to it isn't there.

[image: Logged out version]

Comment: Just track a smaller badge? Raising the tag name length limit to 35 characters does have unanticipated side-effects....